# Load plugin DLL into WebAPI application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dll

I have to load a plugin DLL into a WebAPI application. So I made a custom IPlugin interface that exposes the actions a plugin can react to inside the existing controllers, plus I want to allow the plugin DLL to provide more routes. So I cannot add the DLL into the References list, I have to load it dynamically based on a config file entry.

Therefore, I added ExamplePlugin.DLL to my WebAPI's bin directory (`C:\users\Alexander\Source\Repos\Testbed\WebAPI\bin`) and referenced it from web config's AppSettings:

```
<add key="ExamplePlugin" value="ExamplePlugin.dll" />
```

and try to load it like this:

```
string dllRelativePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[possiblePlugin];
FileInfo dllFileInfo = new FileInfo(dllRelativePath);
Assembly dllAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllFileInfo.FullName);
foreach (Type type in dllAssembly.GetExportedTypes())
{
    if (typeof(IPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    {
        IPlugin i = (IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        PluginManager.Add(i);
    }
}
```

However, the error message says:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not load file **c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\ExamplePlugin.dll**:
>   Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. (Ausnahme von
>   HRESULT: 0x80070002)

Why is my WebAPI DLL searching in the wrong folder and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map your path to your application folder otherwise it will assume the file is in System32.

```
string dllPlugin = "ExamplePlugin.dll";
FileInfo dllFileInfo = new FileInfo(MapPath("~/bin/" + dllPlugin));
Assembly dllAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllFileInfo.FullName);
```

Comment: For those who can't find `MapPath`: I have successfully tested [`HostingEnvironment.MapPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx).